# Build a model sequence or merge models in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, arcgis-9.3, merge, model

This is surprisingly difficult to search for, so I'll ask though it may be a silly question. Is it possible to chain several model-builder models in sequence, such that one will automatically run with the precondition that a prior model has executed? There are plenty, so it seems more sensible than a merge, but I would be interested in that as well.

Comment: which software are you using?

Comment: I believe what I want is a 'sub-model' which seems to exist for arcgis 10.0, but not 9.3.1. I wonder if there's a workaround. Probably a python script.

Comment: just asking, because other GIS software have modelbuilders as well (QGIS)

Comment: Check out the ESRI help section on integrating a model within a model: http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//002w0000007p000000

Comment: ^ indeed, but again, that's for 10.0 and above.

Comment: Consider editing your arcgis-10.0 tag.

Comment: Polygeo added that, not me. *removed*

Answer (score 1):

You can just drag&drop your already built model into the new model

Comment: It's 9.3.1. I realize you can copy paste into an existing model, though it doesn't seem to link at first glance. Maybe it just needs preconditions. But in any case, I'm more interested in models running consecutively than merging them in one, ugly pile. We're talking 12+ models.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to try… gp.AddToolbox("c:/mytoolboxes/tools.tbx") gp.ModelName() or gp.ModelName_ToollName() (or vice versa, not sure), and make sure that the toolbox has an alias. With the script-tool in the toolbox, drag and drop to the model and link (or use precondition? it doesn't use any input variables). That should run another model.